# c# WPF Cant get Parent window from second level window

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am new to WPF and .NET programming. I am designing a POS application where data flow looks like the following:

1. **Home** window has buttons-Brand and Inventory.
2. Clicking on Inventory button opens a new window- **Inventory** with all the inventory items. Each inventory row has a corresponding button.
3. When an inventory row button(from step 2) gets clicked, there is an entry in datagrid in the Home window.
4. When I click on Brand button, a new window -**Brand** with different brands appears.
5. When a brand is now clicked, Inventory window (step 2) opens with items filtered as per brand value.

Now my problem is, I am able to load Home window datagrid from Inventory window when Inventory button is clicked, but when the inventory window opens by clicking on a brand from Brand window which in turn opens from clicking on Brand button on Home window a null exception is being given.

I have the following query which fires on clicking of an inventory item row button:

```
private void btnSelect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Home myObject = Owner as Home;

       Inventory item = (Inventory)lstInventory.SelectedItem;

        myObject.BillInsert(item.Local.ToString(), "1",     item.Price.ToString());           
    }
```

In the first case, myObject returns valid value but it returns null in the second case.

---

In Inventory.xaml.cs, I have defined a constructor for Inventory which accepts parameter- BrandId like this:

```
public OpenInventory(int? attributeID, string attributeName=null) : this()
```

When Inventory button is clicked, this method is fired as below:

```
private void btnInventory_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenInventory opInv = new OpenInventory(null);
        opInv.Owner = this;
    }
```

When Brand row button is clicked, the method is fired from Brand window as below:

```
private void btnBrand_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button _button = (Button)sender;

        OpenInventory window = new OpenInventory(Convert.ToInt32(_button.CommandParameter.ToString()), "BrandId");
    }
```

Thus, same Inventory Window is opened on clicking of both-Inventory button in Home screen and Inventory row button in Brand screen.

On clicking of Inventory button, the given button select event is triggered:

```
private void btnSelect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Home myObject = Owner as Home;

       Inventory item = (Inventory)lstInventory.SelectedItem;

        myObject.BillInsert(item.Local.ToString(), "1",     item.Price.ToString());           
    }
```

Now the problem is, when Inventory button is clicked directly from Home screen and the row button is clicked, Owner returns- POS.Home value but when it is clicked from Brand Window, Owner returns Null.

Comment: What exactly is `Owner` in `Owner as Home`? There is not enough information given to us to resolve what you are seeing.

Comment: @OmegaMan I have edited my question. Please have a look and suggest if I need to be more clear.

Comment: did you try adding window.owner = this in btnBrand_Click event

Comment: Yes I did. Owner is now returning POS.Brand but myObject is still giving Null.

Comment: If I declare- `Home myObject = Owner as Home;` inside Brand class, myObject returns `POS.Home`. But as Inventory is being invoked from Brand window and Home is one level up, myObject can't be set to Home, I believe.